# Create WiFi Network (WITHOUT TETHERING) using ESP8266 CP2102 Arduino?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mobile-phone, arduino

Hi no idea if this is possible, but thought I would as some of you smart folk.

So I have a holiday home WITHOUT WiFi, but I have a phone with unlimited 3G/4G connection and an Arduino WiFi module board. Is it possible to connect the phone to the arduino wirelessly (or wired) and get the arduino to use the 3G/4G signal from the phone to host it's own network, therefore giving me a miniature internet capable network! Any ideas would be a appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Good question, however I think this could be moved to https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ to get a better answer.

Comment: You might get in trouble if you copy the question, so see if it can be moved instead.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I flagged your post and asked the moderator to move it.  Hopefully they can.